How can I read and save the content of a slot in Vue.js at runtime?
I'm currently working on a project with Vue.js and have a problem with using slots.
I have two components: PageView.vue and SlotComponentView.vue In SlotComponentView.vue, there is a slot named Content that is used in PageView.vue. For example, I add an input field to this slot, which is correctly inserted into the component at runtime.
Now, I want to read and save the content of this slot (specifically the value of the input field) from SlotComponentView.vue at runtime. The goal is to implement something like a "savable filter". The filter has a slot where I can place any input (such as text fields), and in SlotComponentView.vue, I want to use a button to read and save those inputs.
Does anyone have an idea how I can access the content of a slot at runtime in order to process the data in the parent component?
Thanks in advance.
Page.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <SlotComponent>
      <template #content>
        <input v-model="inputValue" type="text" />
      </template>
    </SlotComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const inputValue = ref("");
</script>

<style scoped></style>

SlotComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="content" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
function doSomethingWithTheSlotContentBasedOnWhatIsInside() {
  // do something with the slot content
  // i want to save the value of the input given in the slot content from outside
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>



See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . You're supposed to do this in render function, then you can access vnodes and their props and extract data to component state

I think a good workaround for now until a better answer would be:
<template>
  <div>
    <SlotComponent :someNameYouWant="inputValue"> //<==== add this
      <template #content>
        <input v-model="inputValue" type="text" />
      </template>
    </SlotComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const inputValue = ref("");
</script>

then in the component:
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="content" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const props = defineProps(['someNameYouWant'])

function doSomethingWithTheSlotContentBasedOnWhatIsInside() {
  let lorem = props.someNameYouWant
  //if this function must react to the value from props.someNameYouWant, 
  //just add a watcher for props.someNameYouWant that calls your function
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>

